# pytesseract run_and_get_output giving Error 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract's run_and_get_output function . But it is giving me :

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\yp270\AppData\Local\Temp\tess_0va90z8x.'

I am using:
python 3.7.5
pytesseract 0.3.1
tesseract 3.05.02

I have tried :
setting **TESSDATA_PREFIX** to my **tessdata** directory in system environment variables
setting **pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd**  to my **tesseract executable** file

I seems the error comes when pytesseract is trying to open some output file
File "C:\Users\yp270\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_and_get_output

> File "C:\Users\yp270\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 260, in
>
> with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\yp270\AppData\Local\Temp\tess_5nau69o0.'

But, apart from all this , their is no problem while using *image_to_string* , *image_to_data* , *image_to_osd* etc functions. They work perfectly fine. this problem arises only in *run_and_get_output* function.

Can anyone tell where is the problem???

Code:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\yp270\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('image_path')
boxes = pytesseract.image(img)
```

Comment: show some code Yash

Comment: Have you tried to google around?

Comment: I have added code @LV98

Comment: I have tried google it , but their is little information regarding run_and_get_output function . And there are no particular issues related to run_and_get_output in pytesseract github

Comment: @Yashpatel is Pytesseract installed just on your user yp270? or is it also downloaded in `C:\Program Files`?

Comment: Yes @LV98 , it is installed in yp270 not in Program Files folder

Comment: what happens if you run this code: `import os      file =  r"C:\\Users\\yp270\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"    os.startfile(file)`

Comment: it opens a cmd window (tesseract exe file i guess) and closes it immediately

Comment: @LV98 any further suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing a different version of Tesseract? I got the same error as you while using tesseract v5.0.0, but everything worked fine after switching to tesseract v4.0.0.

I used *tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.0.0.20181030.exe* from the older versions section at https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki